# How to grep multi lines

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I want to find all files, who contains two lines: `abc` and `def`. For example,

```
xxx
111abc
yyy
222def333
```

This file should be caught by `grep` because it contains `abc` and `def`.

What should I do? I've tried `grep -rE 'abc.*def' /dir/` but it doesn't work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717772/regex-grep-for-multi-line-search-needed

Comment: Is the relative order of the two substrings important? I.e., would you not want to find files that contain `def` before `abc`?  Judging from you attempted solution, it seems as if you only want files containing `abc` before `def`.

Comment: See also: [grep'ping files for multiple strings (not on the same line)](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/466101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GNU systems, this will do the job for two patterns if the relative order of your matches does not matter:

```
grep -rlZ abc /dir/ | xargs -r0 grep -l def
```

You can chain that if you have more patterns than two:

```
grep -rlZ abc /dir/ | xargs -r0 grep -lZ def | xargs -r0 grep -l xxx
```

or use `find`:

```
find /dir/ -type f -exec grep -q abc {} \; -exec grep -q def {} \; -print
```

This is not very efficient, and another tool than `grep` might be better for that task.

Answer (score 3):

A much more simplified version of `grep` in the `--null-data` mode (`-z`) would be to use a greedy quantifier to match any number of new lines as

```
grep -ozP  'abc(.*\n.*){1,}def' file
```

Or use pcregrep (provided by the [PCRE project](http://pcre.org/)) which by default uses the PCRE regex capabilities. The `-M` enables the multi-line match mode.

```
pcregrep -M 'abc(.*\n.*){1,}def' file
```

Comment: The first command gave me `grep: exceeded PCRE's backtracking limit`

Comment: beware of "grep: memory exhausted" with that.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the case you may have even more complex conditions, we can use Awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\0"} 
     /def/ && /abc/ {print FILENAME}' *
```

Where:

- `RS="\0"` defines a register separator not present in the file (=slurp file) and
- `condition {print FILENAME}` outputs files matching the condition